# Условие для вывода Google AdSense

Tags: google-adsense, рся-яндекс

Недавно начал пользоваться AdSense и заметил что на некоторых страницах сайта не выводит рекламу.
Как можно написать такое правило: Если не выводит рекламу Google, то выводить например рекламу яндекс?

Comment: Да, знаю что за меня код никто не напишет, но может есть какая нибудь статья или подсказка в какую сторону копать.

Comment: в самом адсенсе есть настройка вывода альтернативной рекламы

Comment: не смог найти. где именно эта настройка?

Comment: при создании рекламного блока вроде, давно не заходил.

Comment: а если это рекламный блок для ленты или для стати?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании или редактировании рекламного блока есть вкладка "резервные обьявления". В нем выбираем показывать "объявления с другого URL" и указываем предварительно созданный на нашем сайте html страничку для вывода нужного нам баннера. Спасибо за совет пользователю  Jean-Claude.

Comment: дело в том что не грузиться реклама от Яндекса в iframe Google